# Mapbox - what determines at which zoom level a country label is displayed?

Tags: mapbox

This question is about Mapbox Studio. My use case is showing a map of tax treaties between various countries where some very small countries are important due to being tax havens, for example Mauritius. The label for the island of Mauritius is only displayed at map zoom level 2 or higher whereas it would be useful to show this label at the same prominence as other larger countries. Are the labels baked into the Mapbox tiles or is there a way of controlling when they appear?

I've discovered that you can further filter which countries are shown, but not control this initial setting of which zoom level they appear at.

Comment: Can you share link?

Comment: Sure, you can see this on a simple mapbox demo, like: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/

Comment: Are you looking for like this https://klearvuecabinetry.com/shop/find-your-nearest-menards/

Comment: Err... nope! That map is placing markers, I’m not talking about markers or any additional layers, just the country names included in the Mapbox maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most times, when wanting to change the styling of a particular label, the best approach would be to follow this guide on [customizing label text for a single label](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/customize-label-text/). However, as you mentioned, the island of Mauritius is only displayed at map zoom level 2. We can determine that this is a limitation of how the source data is being included in the Mapbox Streets tileset by following the steps outlined below. Sometimes, data does not appear in a map style because of the way it is *styled* (i.e. how the properties are specified for the relevant [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/)), whereas other times it does not appear because it is simply not included in the underlying [tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset/) at that particular zoom level. Tilesets conditionally include data at different zoom levels for performance enhancements.

1. Navigate to the relevant layer of the style (in this case, the `country-label` symbol layer).
2. Switch to the `Select data` tab. This view allows you to see which labels are visible at a particular zoom level.
3. Explore different zoom levels to see the green features which are included at that zoom level. Here, we see that `Mauritius` is not present at `z1.99` but is at `z2`.

[image: Zoom 1.99]
[image: Zoom 2]

Fortunately, much of the data behind Mapbox Streets comes from [OpenStreetMap](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#new-layer) and you can download the data you need using a number of different methods, to then be included in your map style:

1. Download the data you would like to work with using [Overpass Turbo](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/).
2. From here, you have two options to tile your data - you can either use the [Mapbox Tilesets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilesets) or the Mapbox-created open source tool [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe). You can learn how to adjust the zoom extent of your data using either tool in [this guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/adjust-tileset-zoom-extent/).
3. [Upload the tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/#tilesets) created in the previous step to your Mapbox account.
4. [Add a new layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#new-layer) in your style that references this tileset. You can then specify this layer to show at zoom levels lower than `z2`.

If there are only a few country labels that you'd like to add, it might be easier to manually create a GeoJSON file with the labels and coordinates, and then tile this data with the Tilesets API, rather than downloading the data with Overpass Turbo.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this by ejecting the component that the label belongs to. Then, by selecting the layer and navigating to the "Select data" tab, you can then customize the "zoom extend" and "filters", which control this.