# Show all street names when zooming out

Tags: mapbox, maptiler

I would like to print a map with all the street names with MapTiler or MapBox, especially Rue Robert Schuman:

[Link to static map](https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/static/5.9534,49.5792,17/950x550@2x.png?key=6D0OFtwKjMKZ8x2IYH6a)

[Link to interactive map](https://api.maptiler.com/maps/a738ae17-ebb2-4ecd-b925-571d5c56f3fe/?key=6D0OFtwKjMKZ8x2IYH6a#16.8/49.57935/5.95302)

But if I zoom out to zoom-level 18 (MapBox) or 16 (MapTiler) the names of some streets disappear, although there is enough space to display them.

I have tried to follow the instructions from [MapBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211170/mapbox-what-determines-at-which-zoom-level-a-country-label-is-displayed), but I didn't manage to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the visibility of labels of map features (streets, buildings...)
is defined in the map style (style.json) which is editable via MapTiler Cloud map editor. If you change the visibility of road labels to corresponding levels, they will stay visible in your preferred zoom levels.

I am more than happy to help you set that up, just send me your MapTiler account email via support@maptiler.com and we can have a look at that together.

Thank you

Jiri
MapTiler Support